# Typescript error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for <a bunch of things I haven't referenced in my project>

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a typescript project that was working fine until just after a pull (no one on the project knows of a change that would cause this error). Now, any time I try to start the server or client, I'm getting a long list of errors for packages and libraries I don't reference anywhere in my code:

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'color'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'color-convert'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'compression'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'cross-spawn'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'debug'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'ejs'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'got'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'hapi__joi'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'history'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'http-proxy'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'lodash'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'marked'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'marked-terminal'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'memory-fs'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mkdirp'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'multer'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mustache'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'prettier'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'prop-types'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'q'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'react'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'react-dom'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'react-router'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'react-router-config'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'react-router-dom'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'resolve'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'rimraf'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'signale'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'sockjs'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'sockjs-client'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'spdy'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-bundle-analyzer'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-dev-middleware'.
```

I've tried restarting vscode, `yarn gen:types`, `yarn install`. I'm using Windows and it doesn't seem to happen on Mac?

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to remove node_modules then `yarn install` ?

Comment: any time I try to remove node_modules, it freezes vscode and I need to restart it, and node_modules is still there

Comment: This issue seems to be related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54493, you should remove node_modules outside vscode

Comment: thanks! as it turns out, there somehow ended up a node_modules folder at the root level, and deleting that one was the solve.